# writing int to bytes with value greater than 255

Tags: arrays, debugging, binary, hex, byte

the problem is i'm trying to analyze a binary file.
then i'm kinda stuck how to convert int to byte with value greater than 255
for example i have 0x17b how can i right that as a bytes in file ?

while examining the binary file i notice that 0x17b is equal to 0xfb 0x02 (in bytes)
how did that happen ?

in c# i tried

```
Convert.ToByte(search.Length)
```

and it gives and error that cannot convert into byte because it has more than 255 value in it as in byte the higher byte is `ff`

here's another example for reference

```
0x107 = 0x87 0x02 (in bytes)
0x17B = 0xFB 0x02 (in bytes)
0xAD = 0xAD 0x01 (in bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a value that's bigger than 255 to a byte since this is the biggest value that can be stored on a single byte. What you have to do is to convert to an array of bytes.
In order to do that you can use [`BitConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_BitConverter_GetBytes_System_Int32_) to do the job:

```
int bigValue = 0x17b;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(bigValue);
```

Since `int` is a 4 bytes here, what you will end up with is a `7B 01 00 00` as a bytes representation of this value.

Comment: thank you anyway .. i just realized that you can actually read that array byte from binaryreader.ReadString()